# Admob app keeps crashing due to manifest error

Tags: android, admob

Here is my manifest I have followed the 2018 updated MAN page of banner ads:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.ad">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">



            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is mainActivity file, just using the simple calling for the banner ad I don't know what's going on I am writing the code correctly it doesn't show any error before build :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    private PublisherAdView mPublisherAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
////        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
//        mPublisherAdView = findViewById(R.id.publisherAdView);
//        PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
//        mPublisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        AdView firstAd = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    firstAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
}
```

I am getting this error and the app force closes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.ad, PID: 26343
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.ad/com.example.admin.ad.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2485)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.admin.ad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.admin.ad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.admin.ad-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.admin.ad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

Here is my layout file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
}
```

**I am just a beginner on admob please help!**

Comment: Can you please post the `build.gradle` file and the `layout` file?

Comment: Updated. Kindly see above.

Comment: Thank you. Please add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in the `RelativeLayout` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these answers do not appear too convincing, because they are not addressing the error message.

a) it complains, that the `XML` is invalid, because of a name-space declaration on the wrong node.

> Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class `com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview`

therefore, replace this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

with:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

and instead add the name-space declaration to the top-most node:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

only then the name-space `ads` will be known and can be used.

b) it is not required to set the values in `XML` and `Java` code; setting them once is enough

when setting the values in `Java` code, you could basically remove these lines altogether:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
```

Comment: Thanks the app doesnt crash now but the banner test ad is not showing and in logs it is showing this error :GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.

Comment: did not understand you.. here is the complete error Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See url to firebase
2019-01-17 20:49:47.531 5050-5181/com.example.myapplication E/FA: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled

Comment: @superhuman you are missing `apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"` at the bottom of the module's `build.gradle`... this is a common cause for not having the `google-services.json` processed, which would provide string resource `google_app_id`.

Comment: added the firebase but still the ad is not showing sorry for the delayed response..

Comment: can you please make a test app on git I am still not getting the required results I don't have any android developer friends only web developers..

Answer (score -1):

Delete gradle files , Invalidate caches and Restart the project , also place your

> MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

in the top . Will work happens with me also.

Comment: why are you suggesting to delete gradle files?

Comment: can you post a gist for an example?

Comment: yes , firstly i would recommend invalidate caches and restart . you will find it in file column.

Comment: can you share me a test app on your github profile ? It would be great help I am still not getting the required result.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's happening due to the DEX limit issue, since you have taken multiple big libraries like support libraries.

There are multiple solutions:

**i) Easy and quick:** Enable MultiDex in your application. Though it's easy and quick one but I would not suggest to do that, as we should always drill down the errors and issues to find root cause and build knowledge!

**ii) Little challenging (not so challenging though!):** Analyse your apk and notice the number of methods it's pushing in result apk. This would help you in identifying the culprit and minimising the use!

Based on your analysis, you may then enable proguard for each libraries to minify your code in the resultant apk!